# Cannot Compile .cpp File When Trying To Define Private Var

Tags: c++, g++, private

I am attempting to compile a .cpp file that includes a .h file and then implements the class outlined.

In String.h:

```
using namespace std;

class String
{
        private:

                 int _length;
                 char *data;
                 int getCharArraySize(char arr[]);
```

In String.cpp:

```
 #include "String.h"

 using namespace std;

      /*
       * Private vars and methods
       */
      int String::_length;
      char String::*data;
      int String::getCharArraySize(char arr[])
      {
          //method body
          return 0;
      }
```

When I attempt to compile with g++ I get this error:

```
% g++ String.cpp -c
String.cpp:14:17: error: ‘int String::_length’ is not a static data    member of ‘class String’
int String::_length;
```

I am only having issues with String::_length. I was initially thinking that it was due to _length being private but all the other private methods/vars, compile just fine. I also need to leave this .h file as is so I cannot just make it public. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You don't need that: `int String::_length;` for non static member variables.

Comment: When posting code, please don't include line numbers (it makes it hard to copy the code to try ourselves). Instead use e.g. comments to mark out the lines where you get errors.

Comment: So should I just simply define it within the constructor then? Also, duly noted. I will edit the question.

Comment: Which book are you using to learn C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's exactly as the compiler says: `_length` is not a static member variable. Yet, you are treating it as one by providing it with its own definition. Simply do not do that. **Only *static* member variables should be defined like that.**

The same goes for `data`.

By the way, if you do ever have to define a `char*` variable, then this is wrong:

```
char String::*data;
```

and this is right:

```
char* String::data;
```

Lexical grammar production oddities (inherited from C) notwithstanding, the `*` is part of the *type*, not the name.